# Run vcredist_x86.exe missing MSVCR120.dll

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

Ok, so I was getting an error trying to add a file to a game for full screen windowed mode, and it gave me the error "program cant start missing MSVCR120.dll is missing". Alright, no problem, so everything I searched for said install vcredist_x86.exe, but when I try to run it I get the same error. I cannot figure out or find anywhere how to fix it. I am running 64 bit windows 7 so it is the right file type.

Comment: Did you install the correct version of the VC++ Redistributable Library?  Because my own research points to the incorrect version.  What version does this file use specifically the full version of the linked file is required to help.

Comment: The file i am useing is a .dll file i cant read the code source unless there's some way to do so... But yes I need the x86 version but i have tried the the other 2 just to be safe and still they do not work

Comment: More information about the dll would be nice, because, if you searched and downloaded the `vcredist_x86.exe` you wouldn't install what you need.

Comment: I'm playing ArcheAge and it only has full screen or windowed mode. The dll is basically a script you place in the cache folder of the game to start the game in full screen windowed mode (windowed with no borders) that's all i know unfortunately.

Comment: All I can tell you. If its not working, then you don't have the required files installed, contact the author of the script.

Comment: The version required is 2010 based on this technical article on the game http://forums.archeagegame.com/showthread.php?6428-GUIDE-FAQ-Unofficial-Tech-Support

Comment: i think it is because the script is looking for `c:\program files` when the `x86` programs on 64-bit editions of windows are installed in `c:\program files (x86)`

Comment: Wouldn't matter in this case because a 32-not application is unware of the difference on a 64-bit OS

Answer (score 38):

MSVCR120.dll = Visual C++ 2013 Runtime. Download and install it from here:

**Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013**
https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/3179560/update-for-visual-c-2013-and-visual-c-redistributable-package

Comment: That is the problem the file that is suppose to fix that problem gives me the same missing msvcr120.dll error.

Comment: post a picture of the compete error message.

Comment: Please note: If you’re running an x64 application, it needs the x64 version of the runtime. It’s available on this page, too. In fact, just install both and be done with it. ;)

Comment: @DanielB because he wrote **vcredist_x86.exe** I only linked to the 32Bit version. 64Bit = vcredist_x64.exe

Comment: @magicandre1981 Your link is fine! It provides all three versions (x86, x64, arm).

Comment: AHHH I thought 120 was 2012, derp. I'm guessing 110 is 2012 then.

Comment: @KarlMorrison yes 110 = VS2012 and VS140 = 2015

Comment: I am attempting to install 2012 manually (64-bit), do you know if any additional files except for `msvcr110.dll` and `msvcp110.dll` (both 64-bit versions) are required to be put into the `system32` folder?

Comment: @KarlMorrison what do you mean with additional files? let the installer run and don't do anything else.

Comment: I had to install 32Bit version even though my machine is running 64Bit Windows. As @DanielB said - the version you need depends on your application, and not your system. **Install both!**