# The program can't start because MSVCP120.dll is missing

Tags: windows-7

I am trying to install [sqlitebrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) for Windows 7. But when I run it, I get the following error:

> The program can't start because MSVCP120.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

How do I fix this?

Comment: When you say "*I am trying to download*", do you mean you have already downloaded it and are running the install? Or do you mean you are trying to install it from the Internet?

Comment: You need to install the required vc++ redistributable required by sqlitebrowser.

Comment: Try the answer here: http://superuser.com/questions/827752/run-vcredist-x86-exe-missing-msvcr120-dll